# How do I get a reference to the component added by the last change to an Observable in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

I made a custom Component and reference it from a parent component like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list | async">
  <child-component></child-component>
</div>
```

In the parent component, "list" is defined as:

```
public list: Observable<any[]>;
```

When I add something to the "list" by adding it to the thing the list is observing, and new child-component is added to the DOM.

```
this.list.push(new-object);
// this adds a new child-component to the DOM and 
// returns a value that I need to add into the new object I just pushed
```

**My question is:**
How do I get a reference to the component created by the last addition to the "list" after that push so I can further modify that item with info from the response of the "this.list.push"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few methods

You can set an attribute or property to indicate what element you want to get

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list; let last=last">
  <child-component [item]="item" [attr.last]="last ? true : null" [isLast]="last"></child-component>
</div>
```

You can get the elements or the components

```
@ViewChildren(ChildComponent) children: QueryList<ChildComponent>;
@ViewChildren(ChildComponent, {read: ElementRef}) childElements: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

and you can query for all these elements and just get the last one or get one with a specific attribute or property set

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.children.changes.subscribe(val => {
      console.log('all children: ', this.children.toArray());
      console.log('last children: ', this.children.toArray()[this.children.toArray().length - 1]);
      console.log('child with last attribute: ', this.children.toArray().find(child => child.elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('last') != null));
      console.log('child with isLast property set: ', this.children.toArray().find(child => child.isLast);

      console.log('all childElements: ', this.childElements.toArray());
      console.log(this.childElements.toArray().find(child => child.nativeElement.getAttribute('last') != null)); // <<< doesn't work, don't know why
    });
  }
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! I started down the road of @ViewChildren(ChildComponent) children: QueryList<ChildComponent>; and this.children.changes.subscribe and that looked promising, but then i found another way that I could get the value I wanted into the child component auto-magically on the object creation. But thank you for your reply! I'll probably help me on my next step!